# Matrix display_cell() encoding entities when returning json string

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

I've come across an issue where I've got a celltype which contains array data stored as a JSON string.

When I json_encode the array and return it on save_cell(), display_cell() then returns the JSON quote wrappers as entities?

What I expect:

```
[{"first_name":"Garret","last_name":"Winder"},{"first_name":"Jeff","last_name":"Claeson"},{"first_name":"Paul","last_name":"Burton"}]
```

What I get:

```
[{&quot;first_name&quot;:&quot;Garret&quot;,&quot;last_name&quot;:&quot;Winder&quot;},{&quot;first_name&quot;:&quot;Jeff&quot;,&quot;last_name&quot;:&quot;Claeson&quot;},{&quot;first_name&quot;:&quot;Paul&quot;,&quot;last_name&quot;:&quot;Burton&quot;}]
```

Is there any way I can disable this in Matrix? Presumably if I set the column formatting to 'none' somehow in the cell settings it'll resolve it - I couldn't see how to do that in the docs?

For now I'm just finding and replacing the " entities before decoding...

Thanks
Iain

Answer (score 1):

The issue here seems to be that in Matrix 2.3 `form_prep` is called during the display_cell method:

```
Cell data is now run through form_prep(), just like normal field data
```

If you're outputting the input with `form_textarea` or `form_input` that also calls `form_prep()` leading to the double encoding.